# What is the difference between when we use commands with - symbol or --symbol?

Tags: ubuntu

This might be silly question but I am just excited to know that why we use single - symbol with short form of some flags and double - symbol with full form of flags?

Examples:

```
1) -h & --help
2) -f & --force
```

Can anyone please explain reason for it?

Comment: Typically `-` is for single letter flags and `--` is for spelled-out flags, just like in your example.

Comment: That is the normal convention.  A few commands don't follow the normal convention; e.g. (classic) `tar`, various Java commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single `-` is used as a shorthand flag for the command, while `--` is used with a full name for the same flag.
It is not necessary that all the commands have shorthand flags.
Just like `-h` for `--help`